# Windows 8 unclear focused program in taskbar

Tags: windows-8, taskbar

I am finding it hard to see which program is focused on the task bar. I end up clicking on the taskbar item not realising im looking at it maximized. This minimizes the program.

I hope you can understand my frustration and that i have many monitors each with their own task bar of programs on that monitor.

I did not have a problem with windows 7 as I was able to use classic mode. Not available in windows 8.

**How can I make this easier with windows 8.1?**

Here is a sample of a program that is focused and not focused. Easier that they are side by side, not so easy when there are many more programs across many more monitors.
[image]

**I have tried** going into personalize and modifying various colors and intensity. I have also made the task bar non-transparent using some setting (i think group policy). That helped a little.

I want to avoid high contrast themes as they are way too ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of waiting and looking for Windows solutions of 3rd part solutions.

The solution I am now going to take is to upgrade to Windows 10. Windows 10 clearly shows which program is in focus. Further color and theme settings can enhance this.

The other solution was to downgrade to windows 7 and use the classic theme (which is no longer available on Win8).